# Volver a cargar los sonidos teniendo en cuenta los ciclos de vida en kotlin

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Tengo una aplicación ya subida, pero he descubierto muchos errores con los sonidos que se tienen que reproducir :

```
private lateinit var mediaPlayer1: MediaPlayer
mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lluvia1)


    play_pause1.setOnClickListener {



        if(!mediaPlayer1.isPlaying){
            mediaPlayer1.start()
            play_pause1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause)

        }else{
            mediaPlayer1.pause()
            play_pause1.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.ic_media_play)
        }

    }override fun onPause() {

    mediaPlayer1.pause()
    mediaPlayer2.pause()
    mediaPlayer3.pause()

    super.onPause()
}



override fun onBackPressed() {
    mediaPlayer1.stop()
    mediaPlayer2.stop()
    mediaPlayer3.stop()
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

así tengo el código, y cuando le doy al botón central del menú de navegación de android(circulo) y vuelvo a abrir la aplicación con el botón derecho del menú de navegación de android (cuadrado) solo se reanuda el sonido que se estaba reproduciendo pero los otros no se reproducen, tengo que cerrar la aplicación y abrirla de nuevo, alguna ayuda?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando estas reproduciendo, envias a background (botón redondo) y regresas a la aplicación (botón cuadrado) tienes problemas al reproducir.

En este caso al mandar a segundo plano se llama `onPause()` en donde estas pausando la reproducción, si deseas que al regresar de segundo plano continue la reproducción, implementa el método `onResume()` y revisa si tienes una o varias instancias de `MediaPlayer`, entonces reproduces.

```
override fun onResume() {

    if(mediaPlayer1 !=null){
        mediaPlayer1.start()
    }
    if(mediaPlayer2 !=null){
        mediaPlayer2.start()
    }
    if(mediaPlayer3 !=null){
        mediaPlayer3.start()
    }

    super.onResume()
}
```

Comment: Gracias a tu comentario lo he solucionado aunque de otra forma pero me has hecho ver como modificarlo, en mi caso he vuelto a poner mediaplayer1.create y me funciona bien és mas correcto como me dices tu ? o también es buena opción la de create

Comment: Puedes usar mediaPlayer1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.lluvia1) y en los métodos del ciclo de vida de la Activity (onPause(), onResume(), onDestroy() etc)controlar el funcionamiento.